# Where can I find the page layouts in the 15 hive?

Tags: 2013, hive

I would like to take a look at the default search centers page layout file of Sharepoint in the 15 hive. Anyone have any idea where it is located or how I can find it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The page you are looking for is in this folder directory,

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server
>   Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS

File is named as `SearchResults.aspx`

Comment: Is there a way to see a listing of these pages from the UI if we log into SharePoint from the browser?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version (online/on premise) but if you goto the site settings (make sure you are top level) then site collection then Site Collection Administration then search settings it will tell you the Site Collection Search Results Page etc.

Hope this helps.

S